# Using promisses on Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to use a promise on this code:

```
//Listando arquivos
app.post('/readList', function(req, res) {
  var cleared = false
  var readList = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      fs.readdir(req.body.path, (err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
          console.log(file)
          var fileDetail = {
            name: '',
            local: true,
            filetype: 'fas fa-folder-open',
            filepath: '',
            isFile: false
          }
          if(!cleared){
            listedFiles = []
            cleared = true
          }
          fileDetail.name = file
          fileDetail.filepath = req.body.path + file
          fs.stat(req.body.path + file, function(err, stats) {
            fileDetail.isFile = stats.isFile()
            if(stats.isFile()) fileDetail.filetype = 'far fa-file-alt'
            else fileDetail.filetype = 'fas fa-folder-open'
          })
          listedFiles.push(fileDetail)
        })
      })    
  })
  readList.then(
    console.log('vorta'),
    res.end(JSON.stringify(listedFiles))
  )
})
```

I've putted this line to show the itens listing:

```
console.log(file)
```

And put this line to execute after promise:

```
readList.then(
  console.log('vorta'),
  res.end(JSON.stringify(listedFiles))
)
```

I don't know where is the mistake, but console is showing 'vorta' before the files names.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At least four problems here: 1) You aren't calling `resolve(listedFiles)` to resolve the promise so its `.then()` handler is never called.  And, 2) you need to pass a function to  `.then()`.  3) You also have no error handling for your async operations.  And, 4) you seem to be assuming that `fs.stat()` is synchronous when it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my earlier comment, there are at least four problems here:

1. You aren't calling `resolve(listedFiles)` to resolve the promise so its `.then()` handler is never called
2. You need to pass a single function to `.then()`
3. You have no error handling for your async operations
4. You seem to be assuming that `fs.stat()` is synchronous when it is not

The best way to attack this problem is to promisify all your asynchronous functions and then use promises for controlling the flow and the error handling.  Here's a way to fix all of these issues:

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');
const readdirAsync = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const statAsync = util.promisify(fs.stat);

//Listando arquivos
app.post('/readList', function(req, res) {
    // add code here to sanitize req.body.path so it can only
    // point to a specific sub-directory that is intended for public consumption
    readdirAsync(req.body.path).then(files => {
        return Promise.all(files.map(file => {
            let fileDetail = {
                name: file,
                local: true,
                filepath: req.body.path + file
            };
            return statAsync(fileDetail.filepath).then(stats => {
                fileDetail.isFile = stats.isFile();
                fileDetail.filetype = fileDetail.isFile ? 'far fa-file-alt' : 'fas fa-folder-open';
                return fileDetail;
            });
        }));
    }).then(listedFiles => {
        res.json(listedFiles);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

FYI, this is kind of a dangerous implementation because it lists files on ANY path that the user passes in so any outsider can see the entire file listing on your server's hard drive.  It could even list network attached drives.

You should be limiting the scope of the `req.body.path` to only a specific file hieararchy that is intended for public consumption.

Comment: See the security note I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked fine.
Talking about path listing I put an preset place on server side.

Answer (score 2):

Here you're passing two params:

```
readList.then(
   //#1 In this case you're executing the log function and cause that the message is being printed.
   console.log('vorta'), 
   res.end(JSON.stringify(listedFiles)) //# 2
)
```

So, you need to pass a function

```
readList.then(function() {
   console.log('vorta');
   res.end(JSON.stringify(listedFiles));
})
```

Further, you need to call the function `resolve` within the async logic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a **function** to `then`.

As it stands, you are calling `log` and `end` **immediately** and passing their return values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working copy of your code, I have made few changes that you can omit since those are only to give you a working code:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.post('/readList', function(req, res) {
    //Assuming sample data coming in req.body
    //Remove this when you run at you side
    req.body = {
        path: 'temp_dir'
    };

    var cleared = false;
    var listedFiles = [];
    //Promising readList :)
    function readList(){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // Suppose req.body.path is 'temp_dir' and it has 2 files
            fs.readdir(req.body.path, (err, files) => {
                console.log(files);
            //in following commented code you can do what you need 
            /*files.forEach(file = > {
             console.log(file);
             var fileDetail = {
             name: '',
             local: true,
             filetype: 'fas fa-folder-open',
             filepath: '',
             isFile: false
             }
             if (!cleared) {
             listedFiles = [];
             cleared = true;
             }
             // really? you can think of it later!!
             fileDetail.name = file;
             fileDetail.filepath = req.body.path + file

             // I changed below to avoid surprises for you in data!
             const stats = fs.statSync(req.body.path + file);
             fileDetail.isFile = stats.isFile();
             if (stats.isFile())
             fileDetail.filetype = 'far fa-file-alt';
             else
             fileDetail.filetype = 'fas fa-folder-open'
             listedFiles.push(fileDetail);
             });*/
            resolve(listedFiles);
        });
        });
    }

    readList().then((data) => {
        console.log('vorta');
        // data here will be containing same data as listedFiles so choose your way of doing, I would recommend to go with data
        res.send(JSON.stringify(listedFiles)); // fine
        // res.send(JSON.stringify(data)); // better and recommended
    });
})


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```